# How to get Application labels of Installed applications

Tags: android, process

My question is how to get labels of all those applications which are installed on android.
As I am trying

```
pm = (PackageManager)getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> list = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : list) {
        try {
                deviceApps.add((String) appInfo.loadLabel(pm));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But it does not work.Please help me.
regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the complete code:

```
ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    String description = (String) p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(pm);
    String  label= p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    String packageName = p.packageName;
    String versionName = p.versionName;
    String versionCode = p.versionCode;
    String icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
//Continue to extract other info about the app...
}
```

**Note:** Add this permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: plz explain what do you mean by label localized? check this link too:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html

Comment: I mean is it the Application Name in the locale language? Or is it somekind of default (eng?) Applabel? And if not how could one access app labels in diffrent languages?

Comment: I have tried with eng only, try with another language and I guess it will give the desired result.