# android get package icon

Tags: android

Currently I know that I can get all package icon from package manager. But, I just want to get those icons in the launcher. If I get the List from package manager, I will get those system's apk such as bluetooth or launcher. Is there anyone knows how to make it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167343/how-to-get-application-labels-of-installed-applications/8167422#8167422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all the packages and out of those packages find out which one has intent filter defined for action.MAIN & category.LAUNCHER.

You can use [getLaunchIntentForPackage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) for this.